# How much energy per area or volume is the solar wind producing?

Tags: electricity, estimation, power, solar-system, solar-wind

Would it be possible to erect essentially a giant loop of wire in interplanetary space to create an electric generator? If so, how much power can we get?

Comment: Did you try to do a back-of-an-envelope-calculation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The energy in solar wind particles is much less than the energy in light. You would do better with solar panels, or just heating from absorbing light.

You can find enough to do some calculations here. [The Solar Wind Energy Flux](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/221669340_The_Solar_Wind_Energy_Flux#pf9). See page 203 for mass density and speed of the slow and fast solar wind. Keep in mind this is rough. The solar wind goes up and down with the solar cycle. Gravity slows the solar wind as it travels away from the Sun. And other things are going on that affect its energy.

Taking the values in the link, the slow wind has a density of $0.8 \cdot 10^{-20}$ kg m/s$^2$ and travels at $4 \cdot 10^5$ m/s. So the kinetic energy in a cubic meter is $6.4 \cdot 10^{-10}$ Joule. If you set up a $1$ m$^2$ collector, $4 \cdot 10^5$ m$^3$ of solar wind would pass through it each second, so the total power available for harvesting would be $2.5 \cdot 10^{-4}$ Watts.

The fast solar wind energy is similar.

By contrast, [NASA](https://www.grc.nasa.gov/www/k-12/Numbers/Math/Mathematical_Thinking/sun12.htm) says the solar power passing through that same square meter on Earth is about $1370$ Watts.

Comment: A typical ram pressure at 1 AU (i.e., near Earth) is about 1 nPa for reference.  Inside the orbit of Mercury (i.e., inside ~0.3 AU), the speed is similar or slower than at 1 AU and the density is only a factor of ~5-15 times larger so the ram pressure is still only in the 10s to 100 nPa.  However, near closest approach for _Parker Solar Probe_ the team expects that both solar radiation and ram pressures will affect the pointing direction of the spacecraft resulting in lots of necessary corrections.